# Find greater date for a datetime column in gridview with current date asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, gridview

I have a gridview, along with a date column of MM/dd/yyyy format. 
I need to highlight rows in my gridview, if the date is lesser than the current date.

my codes goes,

```
 protected void grdAssignment_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string curDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
                if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text < Convert.ToString(curDate))
                {
                   //color code
                }
        }
}
```

> Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Could you format your code a little better please?

Comment: sorry, what do U mean by format?

Comment: try `if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Rows.Cells(2).Text) < DateTime.Now) { ...` You need to compare dates, not strings.

Comment: I tired this, I m still getting error, in the conversion part of Convert.ToDateTime(e.Rows.Cells(2).Text) itself..please help

Comment: Why are you using single quotes `MM'/'dd'/'yyyy` in your datetime string formats? please see the valid custom datetime string formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

```
try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DateTime dtRow = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Row.Cells[2].Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;
            int result = DateTime.Compare(dtRow, curDate);
            if ( result < 0 )
            {
               //color code
            }
    }
```

**Note:** You need to add `using System.Globalization;` to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[2].Text) < curDate)
            {
               //color code
            }
    }
```

Comment: I tired this as well, I m getting error on the conversion part of (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[2].Text)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error, use TryParse

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(e.Rows.Cells(2).Text, out dt))
            {
                if (dt < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    //color code
                }
            }
}
```